# Restrict Wordpress File Type Uploads by User Type

Tags: php, functions, uploads

I'm looking to restrict all users (other than admins) to only be able to upload images e.g JPG's and PNGs allowed for all users but still allow admins to upload pdfs etc. (Or even better would be to only prevent unregistered users from uploading anything other than JPGs and PNGs!)

I've been trying the following functions.php code but it still seems to restrict admins from uploading PDFs:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restict_mime'); 
function restict_mime($mimes) { 
if(!current_user_can(‘administrator’)){
    $mimes = array( 
                'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 
                'png' => 'image/png', 
    ); 
}
    return $mimes;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Did you exactly copy this code to your `functions.php`? The input value for `current_user_can()` is wrapped with `‘` and `’`, you should use `'` instead.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked such a simple thing @JackJohansson. Thankyou! That's done the trick as far as I can tell :)

Comment: You are welcome! Happens sometimes, hours of investigation ends into a single period or comma! :D

Comment: I've posted an answer for future visitors. If it fully solved your problem, please do consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: using a user role in `current_user_can()` will likely trigger a `_doing_it_wrong()` in the near future. Instead of a role, you should be using a capability with that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your conditional:

```
current_user_can(‘administrator’)
```

The input value is wrapped in `‘ ’`, which should be wrapped in `' '` instead. Right now, because `‘administrator’` is neither a role nor capability, the above will always return a false value, therefore

```
if(!current_user_can(‘administrator’))
```

will always return `true`, which will restrict the mime type for everyone, including administrators. The correct form will be :

```
if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) { 
    //CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code wasn't working is because you have a typographical error in your code. That code is actually triggering an error. You can enable [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see the error.

But that's not really what's wrong with you code. What's really wrong is that you are using a function that checks a [user capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) and trying to check a user's role. This works because of how WordPress handles roles and capabilities, but it is not the correct way to check a user's role.

In fact, using a user role in `current_user_can()` will likely trigger a `_doing_it_wrong()` in the near future. See [#38653 Trigger a doing it wrong when checking a role name as a capability](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38653). Using `current_user_can()` to check a user role has been wrong for a very long time. See this 2006 post, [How to check if a WordPress user is an “administrator”](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/27/how-to-check-if-a-wordpress-user-is-an-administrator/), by WordPress lead developer Mark Jaquith

Instead of a role, you should be using a capability with that function.

If you want to check a user's role, then you should do something like the following. There's really no good way to check what role a user has, because they can have multiple roles, and because the user capabilities are not guaranteed to be the same as the roles they are a part of.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse_263936_upload_mimes' ); 
function wpse_263936_upload_mimes( $mimes ) { 
  if( ! in_array( 'administrator', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
    $mimes = array( 
      'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 
      'png' => 'image/png', 
    );
  }
  return $mimes;
}
```

If you want to continue using `current_user_can()`, you should check a capability such as `promote_users` or `manage_options` which by default is only applied to the administrator role.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse_263936_upload_mimes' ); 
function wpse_263936_upload_mimes( $mimes ) { 
  if( ! current_user_can( 'promote_users' ) ) {
    $mimes = array( 
      'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 
      'png' => 'image/png', 
    );
  }
  return $mimes;
}
```

Or you could even define the `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` constant in your `wp-config.php` and add the `unfiltered_upload` capability to the administrator role and check for that.